# SQL : Get the max elements in a join?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetch the row which has the Max value for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-row-which-has-the-max-value-for-a-column)

I have two tables

```
1. A table USER with a USER_ID, NAME, ...
2. A table STATUS with a STATUS_ID, PEOPLE_FK (foreign key to USER_ID), LABEL, DATE_START...
```

A USER can only have one active status. I use the DATE_START field to keep the history of all status of the user. I never delete a status. If I create a join between USER and STATUS I can easely get all my users with all they status. BUT I would like to create a query to retriev all my users with they last status only. Is it possible ? What shoul I use ?

Comment: Try a subquery to filter out the status, then do a join of status to user.

Comment: for the efficiency and simplicity i would suggest to have only 1 status in the table and to keep the history in the separate table (i.e `STATUS_HISTORY`). This means you have to eiither use triggers or do 2 queries on update/insert

Comment: @davidmontoyago I'm not a DBA. I tried and I'm still looking for a solition on the web.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Why do you want to know the database I use? I'm looking for a standar SQL solution.

Comment: @Imre L I don't have the power to modify the schema of the database.

Comment: @Magnus Yes, possible but I didnt find it with my search criteria.

Comment: @TimSchmelter The answers in that thread are SQL server 2005/Oracle compatible and some are general SQL compatible.

Comment: @DranDane we want to know the database you are using because some SQL  syntax is database specific.

Answer (score 0):

Join like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM USER   U
JOIN STATUS S ON U.USER_ID = S.USER_ID
              AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM   STATUS S2
                WHERE  S2.USER_ID = S.USER_ID 
                AND    S2.START_DATE > S.START_DATE
              )
```

This will only join those status records for which there doesn't exist another status for the same user and with a more recent date

Comment: I edited my question and your answer

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select * from user 
inner join 
(
   select * from status
   inner join 
      (select max(Date_start) as maxdate, status_id as id  
           from status group by Status_id)   d
   on status_id = d.id and Date_start = d.maxdate
)d1 
on userid =d1.People_fK
```

Comment: @DranDane - is that work for you ...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using SQL-Server :

You can use a cte with `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT U.USER_ID, U.NAME, U.DATE_START, S.STATUS
    ,   RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY S.STATUS_ID ORDER BY U.DATE_START DESC)
    FROM USER U INNER JOIN STATUS S ON U.User_ID=S.PEOPLE_FK
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
    user a, 
    status b 
where 
      a.user_id = b.poeple_id 
  and b.start_date = (select max(start_date) 
                             from status c 
                             where c.people_id=b.people_id)
```